# Use PHP to determine the type value from input

Tags: php, input, types

My question, it´s very short.

is it possible to detect the kind of types we send as POST from a form?

If I have some fields and one field for each input type as text, the other textarea, the other file, etc, is it possible to use Php to detect, in each case, the type from these fields.

```
<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="test1" value="ok">
<textarea name="text2"></textarea>
<input type="file" name="test3" value="ok">

</form>
```

And finally determine whether the type is text, textarea, file, etc

I know it´s possible with Jquery buy i don´t find nothing about this with php.

**Thank´s for the help in advanced**

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST['text2'])){echo "OMG! text-area type value submitted";}`

Comment: This get value from input but i can get the type no value send

Answer (score 1):

No, request contains only key-value pairs. But you can add additional hidden fields that passes these data. i.e. (for larger forms I's suggest it automaticaly with JS):

```
<input type="hidden" name="text2_type" value="textarea">
<input type="hidden" name="test3_type" value="file">
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="types[text2]" value="textarea">
<input type="hidden" name="types[test3]" value="file">
```

**Other solution**

Also you can just introduce naming convention for your fields, i.e.:

`<textarea name="text2_textarea"></textarea>`

or

`<textarea name="textarea[text2]"></textarea>`

so in your PHP you can check if key ends with `_texteraea` or is in array `$_POST['textarea']` to determine the type o field.